# Synonyms search functionality in Solr

Tags: search, solr, synonym

I am using Solr search engine on my website and need to implement the synonyms search. A have a list of synonyms in a `synonyms.txt` file.

For example, a user searches for a *‘Sample65477’* term, the results should show first all pages with the exact match for *‘Sample65477’*, then pages with the exact match for a *‘SampleSYS65477’* synonym, then partial match for *‘Sample65477’*,  then partial match for *‘SampleSYS65477’* etc.

Could you please advise me on how I should approach this requirement?

Comment: Use one field for each of your requirements (and define a field type for that requirement) and apply boosts accordingly (so boost exact matches by 1000, exact matches with synonyms by 500, partial matches without synonyms by 50 and no extra boosting for partial matches with synonyms. You can use `qf` to apply boosts.

Comment: I don't think you can control the boost of synonyms applied via the synonyms.txt file.